# Prespective transform - OpenCV displays a mirror image

Tags: java, opencv, transform

I tried using the code given as an answer on this link: [How to find the corners of a Rect object in openCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084098/how-to-find-the-corners-of-a-rect-object-in-opencv)

I must acknowledge that this code works very well except some of the parts as you can see below:

I tried feeding the image [source image][image]

and got a weird result back [resulting image]: [image]

As you can see, the resulting image is tilted 90 degrees clockwise and also the text is mirrored.

Can anyone please help me out in this and suggest what changes should I make in the above code in order to get the correct output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the issue with the program. It was due to the ordering of the coordinates. The coordinates of the original image were not according to the coordinates I was using for the resulting image.

The changed the order of the co-ordinates in the original image as Bottom-left, Top-left, Top-right and Bottom-right. I set this because I was taking the same ordering for my resulting image.

Hope it helps.[image]

Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was going crazy when I also got the same issue. You hit the right spot. Thanks again for saving my time.